# how to set jmsTemplate send timeout?

Tags: hornetq, jmstemplate

I'm using JmsTemplate as producer to send messages to hornetQ;

I'm using singleConnectionFactory

If set wrong port (which is open on the server side, such as one other HornetQ port), the producer is blocked

How could I set 'send timeout' ???